# How can you simultaneously change the name of a song in iTunes and the actual file

Tags: itunes, macos

When I download music it automatically goes very quickly to iTunes before I can change the name of the download to just the song's name. How can I change the name so that it then changes in iTunes as well as the actual file without having to do it twice?

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to do it using an app, there are a few apps that do it.

1-**One is freeware and called "[Tagger](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/41285/tagger)"**,

Here is what Tagger allows you to do, in terms of renaming options:

[image]

2-**another app is called "[Tune Instructor](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/28504/tune-instructor)"**, which works as an iTunes plug-in (freeware too).

3-**another one is called "[Metadatics](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/46463/metadatics)"**. This one is shareware (9$).

4-If you're good at more complex solutions, then maybe looking into **[Applescript]**[5](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html) would be a good idea.

5-**[Doug's free iTunes scripts](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=filerenamer)** also have iTunes applescripts to help you rename your files.

[image]

I didn't try the 2 and 3, but they're probably all good solutions. 5 is usually a very good source of scripts. Try them and chose what you like best!